# Checking null value in Scala for Java data type

Tags: scala

I have call in Scala code which give Java `Double` type which can be `null` how can I check between null and non-null value in Scala code?

```
val myJavaDoubleValue: Double = thirdpartyCall.collectValue()
if(myJavaDoubleValue == null) {
  println("Is NULL")
} else {
  println("Is NOT NULL")
}
```

Any suggestion on doing this in Scala way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an Option:

```
val myJavaDoubleValue: Option[Double] = Option(thirdpartyCall.collectValue())
```

The above will result in `None` if the result is null, otherwise in `Some(actualValue)`.

See [Option.apply()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$@apply[A](x:A):Option[A])

Answer (score 7):

Scala supports `null` in the same way as Java. So your code is syntatically correct.

However, a more modern approach would be to make sure your code almost never can touch `null` values. In order to do that, one possible way is using Scala [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option) class. An `Option[T]` is an value that may or may not be defined. A defined option is represented by `Some[T]`, while a non-defined option is represented by `None`.

`Option(thirdpartyCall.collectValue())` will return a `Option[Double]`. There are multiple ways to check the value contained in an `Option`, one of the Scala-idiomatic ways to perform what you want to do is [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html):

```
Option(thirdpartyCall.collectValue()) match {
  case Some(value) =>
    println(s"value is defined: $value")
  case None =>
    println("value is not defined")
}
```

However, `Option` is much more powerful than that. It supports methods like `map`, `flatMap` and `fold` which allow you to be even more expressive, for example:

```
def optionIsDefined[A](a: A) = Option(a).fold("not defined") { value => s"defined with value: $value" }

scala> optionIsDefined(42)
res2: String = defined with value: 42

scala> optionIsDefined(null)
res3: String = not defined
```

[This](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) is a great newcomers' friendly guide on `Option`.